# AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'username'

Tags: python, bots, telegram, coroutine, telethon

***Hi! im new and i request an assistance.***

so i downloaded this code from github called telegram auto reply and i run it, but then i got this error:

```
"C:\Users\user\Downloads\Compressed\telegram-auto-reply-master\main.py", line 36, in handle_new_message
    me = await client.get_me().username
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'username'
```

[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIfPY.png)

**and this is the main.py code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# A simple script to print some messages.
import time
import re
import json
import random
import os
from asyncio import sleep
from pprint import pprint

from telethon import TelegramClient, events, utils
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv() # get .env variable

session = os.environ.get('TG_SESSION', 'printer')
api_id = os.getenv("API_ID")
api_hash = os.getenv("API_HASH")
debug_mode = os.getenv("DEBUG_MODE").upper() == "TRUE"

proxy = None  # https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks

# Create and start the client so we can make requests (we don't here)
client = TelegramClient(session, api_id, api_hash, proxy=proxy).start()

# create a sender list to check if user already send private message or mention
senderList = [] 

#read json file and prepare quiz to send later
with open('quizzes.json') as json_file:
    quizzes = json.load(json_file)

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def handle_new_message(event):
    
    me = await client.get_me().username
    from_ = await event.client.get_entity(event.from_id)  # this lookup will be cached by telethon
    to_ = await event.client.get_entity(event.message.to_id)

    needToProceed = from_.is_self if debug_mode else not from_.is_self and (event.is_private or re.search("@"+me.username,event.raw_text))
    if needToProceed:  # only auto-reply to private chats:  # only auto-reply to private chats   
        if not from_.bot and event:  # don't auto-reply to bots
            print(time.asctime(), '-', event.message)  # optionally log time and message
            await sleep(1)  # pause for 1 second to rate-limit automatic replies   
            message = ""
            senderList.append(to_.id)
            if senderList.count(to_.id) < 2:
                message =   f"""**AUTO REPLY**
                \nHi @{from_.username},
                \n\nMohon maaf boss saya sedang offline, mohon tunggu sebentar.
                \nSilahkan lihat-lihat [imacakes](https://www.instagram.com/ima_cake_cirebon) dulu untuk cuci mata.
                \n\n**AUTO REPLY**"""
            elif senderList.count(to_.id) < 3:
                message =   f"""**AUTO REPLY**
                \nMohon bersabar @{from_.username}, boss saya masih offline """
            elif senderList.count(to_.id) < 4:
                message = f"""**AUTO REPLY** 
                \n@{from_.username} Tolong bersabar yaa """
            else:
                random_number = random.randint(0,len(quizzes) - 1)
                question = quizzes[random_number]['question']
                answer = quizzes[random_number]['answer']
                message = f"""**AUTO REPLY**
                \n @{from_.username}, Main tebak-tebakan aja yuk 
                \n {question}
                \n {answer}
                \n """
            
            if message != "":
                await event.reply(message)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

i dont really know whats wrong because im new and dont know much about coding so *if anyone willing to help me i really appreciate that* :)

***Thank You for anyone helping me :)***

Comment: `usermame = (await client.get_me()).username`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is with `me = await client.get_me().username`.

According to the [Telethon Quick-Start](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/quick-start.html#quick-start), `client.get_me()` is an [awaitable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-awaitable). This means that to get the return value you must `await` it, as in `await client.get_met()`. Before that, the result of `client.get_me()` is a [coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines). Therefore `await client.get_me().username` does not work because when you try to access the `username` attribute `client.get_me()` is still a coroutine.

The Quick-Start actually does this

```
me = await client.get_me()
username = me.username
```

Comment: pardon me but im very new,

Comment: does it mean i have to change the code from this:

Comment: ```me = await client.get_me().username```

Comment: to this:::::::::::::::::::::::

Comment: ```me = await client.get_me()```

Comment: ```username = me.username```

Comment: @FerdiAnsyah, yes that should be the fix

Comment: `File "C:\Users\heyxferdi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 461, in get_input_entity
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Could not find the input entity for PeerUser(user_id=1973930356) (PeerUser). Please read https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/entities.html to find out more details.`

Comment: @FerdiAnsyah, that is a new error that is probably caused by the next line: `from_ = await event.client.get_entity(event.from_id)`. Would you please mark this as the answer and then create a new question because it is a new problem. Before creating a new question, please try reading the document that is referenced in the error.

Comment: Hi!, here is the new question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69386740/valueerror-could-not-find-the-input-entity-for-peeruser