# ValueError (Could not find the input entity) when using Telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Code:

```py
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

async def FirstFunction():
    await client(AddChatUserRequest(
        chat_id=1234,
        user_id=1234,
        fwd_limit=10 
    ))

client.loop.run_until_complete(FirstFunction())
```

Error:

```py
ValueError: Could not find the input entity for PeerUser(user_id=1234) (PeerUser).
```

Note: I am using the same id for chat_id + user_id

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: Could not find the input entity for PeerUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69386740/valueerror-could-not-find-the-input-entity-for-peeruser)

Comment: Note that mass-adding users is considered spam and will likely get both the group and account banned.